# Convert this function from php to ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I have this function and I tried to convert it to ruby 1.9.3 (to be used on ruby on rails 3.2.13) but I can't get the same hash that this php function returns.

this what I am using in ruby so far:

```rb
keypair = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open(Rails.root.join('sec', 'private_key.pem')))
@encrypted_string = keypair.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new, @data)
@encrypted_string = Base64.encode64(@encrypted_string)
```

This is the function in php:

```php
function SignData($text, $privateKeyFile) {

$private_cert = $privateKeyFile;     
$f = fopen($private_cert,"r");  

if($f)
  $private_key = fread( $f, filesize($private_cert) );    
else
  return "";    
fclose($f);    
$private_key = openssl_get_privatekey($private_key);         
if(openssl_private_encrypt(md5($text), $crypt_text, $private_key))
{     
   base64_url_encode($crypt_text) . "\n";   
}   
  return "";   
}
```

This is the hash returned in php:

> xJCl3YZVEkXjt_pTPHl9FjpebpDcdMtgZzGFo0LsO_PFyQ8lwdUpKxR_XhK1DGfywVr4-hPxtDqSOHMcp7fM-eYK5GqGVasUh80qRiVLjw6Zeh4NPCk1qxsSm4X3gl0sv13dBb5FvDwV6QcLyo7vyNweqUH_Cpq_WmWrNY3px5Y,

This is the one I got in ruby:

> DTilW98pHOep/5qc7H+iBYPdbFNZGKWW0c0XFo5YfrWfqKLPzzLTygRQAiFY
>   whVX8+I0FYAOg3+QqyH0jpcGaFbSVQefU7gDIfT+tHKqSCKmLZwVQas5SQ3j
>   o+m8V+iv/ZgGuHD0U8dNZwO4zkqJAPMPJFvdOeHJVxb77lCBtNU=

Maybe I need to remove the header and footer in the .pem file?

Comment: You should post your "solved" section as an answer and accept it yourself, that way this question won't be listed as unanswered

Answer (score 1):

For the convinience:

This has done it for the OP:

```
private_key_file = File.open(Rails.root.join('sec', 'private_key.pem'))
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(private_key_file))
digest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(@data)
@encrypted_string = private_key.private_encrypt(digest)
@encrypted_string = Base64.encode64(@encrypted_string)
```